# Is it okay to leave a question wrongly dupehammered, type up an answer, and then re-open and post it?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

A user, let's say "Chris", posted a question. Another user, let's say "Robin", with a gold badge in one of the tags, closed it as a duplicate. Chris edited the question to point out why closing it was wrong, it wasn't a duplicate.

Robin continues to interact with Chris in the comments, leaving the question closed. 30 minutes after closing, Robin re-opens the question and less than a minute after that, posts a three-paragraph answer along with a code snippet.

Robin couldn't have used SO's own answer functionality to prepare it as long as the question was closed, and it seems impossible to me that Robin managed to type this all up in less than a minute. The fact that it was closed prevented others from answering, and it would have been easier even for Robin to re-open it as soon as it was clear it was not a duplicate.

This does not seem nice, yet it might not go against any rule we have here. What's the right way to handle this? Should it just be ignored, or should some action be taken to discourage this kind of behaviour?

Note: I do believe that at the time of closing, Robin believed the question was a duplicate.

Comment: *Don't assume malice*....

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm not assuming malice. If I were, I'd have just flagged the answer asking for a mod to step in. That's why ignoring it is one of the options I put in my question. Another might be to simply explain how this comes across to Robin, so that Robin realises it and hopefully doesn't do it again in the future.

Comment: You seem to be... *"it seems like Robin used the fact that the question was closed to prevent others from answering."*

Comment: It isn't that hard to figure out what happened. She composed the answer while having a discussion with the user in comments, which was necessary for her to figure out what the question was actually asking. Then, satisfied, she re-opened the question and shortly thereafter, posted her answer, now fully written. What do you think she should have done differently? I can only think of one thing: edit the question to incorporate the enlightening discussion from the comments.

Comment: @Paulie_D Fair enough, I tried to word that to not imply anything too bad, but if I didn't go far enough I'll try to re-word.

Comment: I agree...the written word can be problematical in these areas.

Comment: @CodyGray I think that as soon as it was clear that it wasn't a duplicate, the question should've been re-opened, and I believe that it was clear to Robin already a while before actually re-opening.

Comment: I've sometimes, while writing an answer, found evidence that I should close as duplicate instead. (Could be a search I did that found a question to close against, or a comment on the Q because someone flagged it as duplicate.) I don't recall ever coming back to reopen and answer in such a case, but I can imagine seeing, after closure, a comment arguing against the closure. If I  then reopen because I find the comment persuasive, why oh why should I not finish my answer and post it? (In other words, the sequence of events may not be quite what you think.)

Comment: @Louis Now *there's* a good point... If Robin prepared an answer *before* closing the question as a duplicate, and if the prepared answer was saved and available after re-opening for immediate posting, that could explain very well what happened without anybody having done anything wrong, and that could be a good reason for not doing anything about it. Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Louis Isn't the changes discarded in such case?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Unsure what you mean by "changes". The site keeps a draft of what we write, and users may use an external editor to compose so  a answer that was abandoned during writing may survive indefinitely.

Comment: I don't really see the problem. Are you insinuating "Robin" misused the dupe hammer to circumvent the [FGITW problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)? Users with a tag gold badge don't need such tactics. They usually can get rep easily enough.

Comment: @Roland To be clear, as I pointed out in my question, I already thought Robin used the dupe hammer to close when legitimately thinking the question was a duplicate. I only thought Robin didn't use the dupe hammer to re-open as soon as it was clear the question wasn't a duplicate, instead waiting a bit. (As Louis's comment and answer shows, I may well have been wrong about that.) I hoped to avoid giving any possible reasons for that, instead only giving a reason why I think that's the wrong thing to do. I agree that the reason being rep would have been extremely unlikely.

Comment: OK. 1) The question was legitimately closed as a duplicate by "Robin". 2) The question got reopened after OP provided additional information. 3) The question was answered. What is the problem? That someone else didn't get the chance to earn some rep? It's unlikely that that someone would even notice the question being reopened after it has been closed for some time. And if "Robin" has engaged with OP as you describe I believe it's only fair that he gets some points as a reward.

Comment: @Roland Your 2) is misleading. The OP provided an explanation why it wasn't a duplicate, not additional information about the question. It already wasn't a duplicate in the first version of the question, it was just closed anyway. Anyway, the problem I saw was that someone else didn't get the chance to answer. That someone else was me. I had voted to re-open the question already and had wanted to compose an answer when it got re-opened, and felt I was denied the chance for no good reason. I don't care about the rep, and I don't believe Robin cares about the rep.

Comment: "*I... had wanted to compose an answer... and felt I was denied the chance...*" - Did your answer not add value to the one posted by Robin? Or was it essentially the same?

Comment: Would you still see a problem if (1) instead of Robin, the reopening and answering were done by Laura, an otherwise uninvolved gold badge owner; or if (2) the reopening and answering happened had happened in a 15 minute interval that you had spent e.g. drinking a cup of tea away from the keyboard?

Comment: @OhBeWise The basic answer would've been the same, but I had wanted to include details that Robin had not. The value would've been enough to post it anyway if Robin and I had both started typing at the same time, and Robin had posted first, but not enough to *start* typing once Robin's answer was posted already. Yes, that's very subjective.

Comment: @duplode If Laura had re-opened the question and at the same time posted an answer, I might have very well asked this same question. If Laura had re-opened the question and Robin, Laura, or anyone else had started typing an answer at that time, posting it before I would've, I would not have asked this question. Anyway, I'm happy with the answer I got here, which is that there's probably nothing wrong.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It is possible that Robin started writing an answer, then found evidence that the question should be closed as a duplicate and decided to close rather than answer. (Evidence could be a search done while writing an answer or finding an auto-comment about the question being a duplicate generated when someone flags or votes to close as duplicate.)

It is furthermore possible that new comments after closure persuaded Robin to reverse and reopen. Then Robin may have just posted the answer that had already been composed before closure.

SO does keep a draft of posts we write. As I recall, for answers, the draft is kept until a new answer is written. But even independently of SO, it is not rare that I compose answers in Emacs and then copy-paste them to SO. I've got probably 5-10 such abandoned answers in files somewhere. So I can see myself easily be in the hypothetical situation above. It has certainly happened that I decided closure was preferable *after* I started composing an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'll leave the question open for a while in case others want to share their thoughts as well, but I'll probably accept this answer.

Comment: This is indeed plausible. I found myself in a similar scenario yesterday: while I was writing an answer, someone found a duplicate and cast a close vote, which led me to dupehammer it. From there it evolved a bit differently, as the OP argued against closure while I was away, and so another hammer-wielder reopened it. Still, if I had reopened the question instead I don't see why I would have to refrain from finishing and posting my answer, after any necessary adjustments to it in light of the reopening were done.

Comment: The answer to the original question as stated in the question title is still probably "no - it is not okay". We don't have to go very far with this: "Is it okay to leave a question wrongly dupehammered(full stop)".  No, it is not okay to leave a question wrongly dupehammered, *especially* if you were the one that applied the dupehammer. What seems to be addressed in this answer is "does this particular sequence: X,Y,Z constitute malice or malfeasance?" I believe the original question still stands (albeit perhaps hypothetical) and is still worthy of a direct answer. It seems to be self-evident.

Answer (score 20):

If all other things are equal, I would tend to err on the side of the hammer wielder just not seeing the non-dupe until they've done some due diligence on the issue. Sometimes when you have a dispute about a dupe, it's helpful to flesh it out, which can produce an answer. So the process can also look like (in addition to Louis' examples)

1. Chris asks Q
2. Robin hammers it
3. Chris respectfully disagrees with Robin
4. Robin looks at it again and realizes there may not be a dupe after all, but isn't sure
5. Robin goes digging around and, after some reading, determines it's not really a dupe after all, but it's in the same vein as the dupe, having done due diligence
6. Robin types an answer up (because it's still fresh in their mind)
7. Robin un-hammers Q
8. Robin answers Q

I think your sticking point is that #6 looks fishy when it precedes #7, when it could just be [overzealousness](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/11/03/guys-who-overdo-it-on-stackoverflow/) to post a potentially good answer. What's easy to forget is that the Q is now open again. If you can outdo Robin's answer then do it. It's also possible to override Robin and reopen it yourself (find another hammer to reopen or convince 4 others to reopen it). Remember, Robin cannot re-hammer it if it's reopened.

The only way I see this being problem (and this is an extreme edge case) is if you have other people wanting to answer the Q, are clamoring to reopen it (i.e. trying to reopen without Robin), and then the hammer pulls that. It would leave a bad taste in a lot of mouths to be sure. In such an instance, I would prefer a case-by-case basis, since there's still the possibility it wasn't done to spite anyone.

Making a rule to say you can't answer a question you've hammered (or you can't answer until X minutes have passed since a reopen) really penalizes the questioner, since a hammer is also probably best qualified to post a useful answer.

Comment: Your "the only way I see this being problem" is exactly what happened and what prompted me to ask this question. I didn't include the details of that because I do not believe that should be relevant to the question of whether Robin did anything wrong: Robin had no reliable way of knowing what's in the minds of other people viewing the question.

Comment: @hvd Ah, well this is making more sense, then. I would say if it's a one-off, just let it go. If there's a pattern of this, I'd bring it to Meta for discussion, because that's problematic if it's happened more than once.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say it's OK so long as the gold badge use did not intentionally close the question as a duplicate to prepare an answer without competition.

Comment: @TylerH what would the situation be if the dupehammerer *did* intentionally close the question to stifle competition? Should that be considered abusive or should that be considered a legitimate (if perhaps somewhat antisocial) use of the powers vested in a legitimately-earned dupehammer? In other words, does a dupehammer vest the holder with the *right* to dupehammer or are they still required to dupehammer according to some set of rules?

Comment: @RobertColumbia I think we can all agree that blatantly using your powers for personal gain is grounds for removal of said powers. Any powers, even mods. The problem is how do you prove intent?

Comment: The situation would probably be a suspension of some duration. There isn't any code for removing an individual privilege in the codebase, @Machavity. The SE team doesn't remove a privilege because it's been abused. Instead, they suspend the user altogether for a certain period of time. And you could "prove" intent insofar as you need to for meting out punishment by showing that the incident happened multiple times... but that's a different discussion.

Comment: @RobertColumbia There's not an explicit rule about using a dupehammer to close questions so that no one else can answer them, I don't think, but there are rules about manipulating the system in unfair ways. I'm pretty sure any moderator would see an intentional dupehammer to prevent competing answers/FGITW as abuse in this regard.

Answer (score -7):

Yes, it's ok.

In almost every answer on this here site I have to emphasize the fact that Stack Overflow is not a forum to serve individuals. But rather a self-proclaimed knowledge base intended for a much wider range of programmers. It means, in the end, that the only **quality of the answer that matters**, while anything else including the feelings of yet another clueless OP, the rage of rep-whores, and whatever else gamification stuff is of no importance at all.

So, as long as your answer is good, and serves not a single individual with their particular typographic error, but can help other people, it doesn't matter which way it has been written.

Otherwise, the answer shouldn't have been written at all.

Comment: This answer suggests that even if Robin had intentionally wrongly closed the question as a duplicate, it would've been okay, since that's unrelated to the quality of the answer. Try that yourself often enough and I can assure you that action will be taken.

Comment: Even though you're giving an answer, this answer doesn't actually seem to address the concern of the question. He's not asking if the answer is good or whether the user should have answered. What he's asking is whether closing a question unilaterally to prevent competition while you write your own answer is OK. OP is not looking for a handwaving-away of his concern. He's looking for either "yes this is OK because that is an inherent power of the dupehammer and it's not abuse" or "no it's not OK because that's unfair/dishonest manipulation of the system"

Comment: @TylerH This answer is saying only the quality of the answer matters, and what I read from that is that YCS believes that any use of the tools is okay so long as the end result is that a good answer gets posted. In other words, there is no such thing as unfair/dishonest manipulation of the system. (YCS: If that's not what you believe, please clarify.) I don't agree with that, but I do believe this attempts to answer my question.

Comment: @hvd Don't sell yourself short. It's okay to get your concerns addressed rather than handwaved away as missing the point.

Comment: @TylerH hvd is right; this is an answer to the question. You are saying that YCS should acknowledge and address a concern that, according to this answer, they consider irrelevant. That isn't a reasonable demand.